# How to execute PRAGMA statements in Android application with io.requery & Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I am investigating performance improvements of Sqlite `PRAGMA` statements on my current Android application.

I have this code as my `RoomDatabase.Callback` `onCreate` function

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesRoomDatabaseCallback(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): RoomDatabase.Callback {
    return object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA temp_store=2;")
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY")
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA auto_vacuum=incremental;")
        }
    }
}
```

However when my application first launches I see this crash in my logcat:-

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my.app, PID: 30620
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only.
    at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
    at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:778)
    at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:764)
    at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:71)
    at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1923)
    at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1864)
    at com.my.app.background.database.hilt.DatabaseModule$providesRoomDatabaseCallback$1.onCreate(DatabaseModule.kt:33)
```

the offending PRAGMA statement is this one

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY")
```

how do you configure sqlite journal_mode in an Android application?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

switching to `query` fixed it

```
db.query("PRAGMA temp_store=2;")
db.query("PRAGMA journal_mode=memory;")
db.query("PRAGMA auto_vacuum=incremental;")
```